# How do I put a link to this divs?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs:

```
   <a href="http://google.com">
     <div id="tabel_albastru_produits">
        <p id="client1">Clients privés</p>
        <div id="paragraf_1">DeLumine propose différents produits pour les clients privés répartis en trois gammes.<br>Nous nous efforçons de vous proposez la solution la plus adequate possible. Notre objectif est de garantir une autonomie énergétique fiables, durable et écologique.</div>

</div>
</a>


   <a href="http://google.com">
      <div id="tabel_verde_produits">
      <p id="client2">Clients professionels</p>
      <div id="paragraf_2">Dans le but de répondre aux besoins spécifiques des entreprises, et de certains particuliers, nous proposons une installation sur mesure. Ainsi, un technicien DeLumine procède à l’analyse de vos besoins en énergie électrique en vue de vous proposer une solution concrète et personnalisée.”</div></a>

</div>
```

This is code CSS:

```
  #tabel_verde_produits
{
        width: 402px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #8CC63F;
        margin-left: 10px;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-top:40px;
        padding-bottom:40px;
        margin-left:50px;

}



#tabel_albastru_produits
{
        width:431px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #264572;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-top:40px;
        padding-bottom:61px;
        margin-left:50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wxhbbw0y/

I want to fix these two div inline sites

If you delete the link to google these two div's, arrange tables in line

Basically I want to put them in line and work links

This is the site:

http://dl.dg-site.com/produits-et-services/

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to position the divs side by side??

Comment: yes...now they are placed side by side but if you put a link only look good

Comment: Nothing changes when i delete the links.

Comment: look website and look as arranged

Comment: I dont understand what your problem is

Comment: I have two div's that are displayed inline at this time
If these sites div insert a link ... it no longer displays in line, right?

Comment: So your problemen entails that when you add a link, the divs wont render side by side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you start looking at `float`

This way you can easily render elements side by side.

```
div.1  {
    float: right;
}
```

You need to make a container element to keep the floating divs in check.

```
<div class="1"> 
<div>1
</div>
<div class="1">2
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my pen, I would recommend that you use bootstrap. Its a html, css, javascript framework. It responsive and it dose most of the heavy lifting. Check it out. 
http://www.bootply.com/0yoAlNcOrW

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.blue {
margin: 20px;
    background: #264572;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .green {
      margin: 20px;
      background: #8cc63f;
       padding: 20px;
      color: #fff;
    }
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="blue">
        <p id="client2">Clients professionels</p>
<div id="paragraf_2">Dans le but de répondre aux besoins
  spécifiques des entreprises, et de certains particuliers, 
  nous proposons une installation sur mesure. Ainsi, un 
  technicien DeLumine procède à l’analyse de vos besoins en énergie 
  électrique en vue de vous proposer une solution 
  concrète et personnalisée.”</div>



      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="green">
        <p id="client2">Clients professionels</p>
<div id="paragraf_2">Dans le but de répondre aux besoins
  spécifiques des entreprises, et de certains particuliers, 
  nous proposons une installation sur mesure. Ainsi, un 
  technicien DeLumine procède à l’analyse de vos besoins en énergie 
  électrique en vue de vous proposer une solution 
  concrète et personnalisée.”</div>

      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you recommend bootstrap here? Since this is a problem related question...